# Get sheet name where selected chart is located

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

While looping through all charts in the book - how can i get name of the sheet on which my chart is located ?

I have folowing code in VBA Excel:

```
    Sub mytest()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Ct As ChartObject
Dim Wb As Workbook

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Wb.ActiveSheet

For Each Ct In ws.ChartObjects
'MsgBox Ct.Chart.Parent.Name
MsgBox Ct.Chart.Name
MsgBox Ct.Chart.Parent.Name

Next Ct

End Sub
```

when i try this code
`MsgBox Ct.Chart.Name`
i get msbbox Name of Sheet & name of Chart in one string:
"Sheet3 Chart2"

when i try this code
`MsgBox Ct.Chart.Parent.Name`
i get Name of Chart:
"Chart2"

but i need to get Name of **Sheet** on which this chart is located
what **property** of Chart should i use?

Comment: Probably by using [Chart.Parent property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.parent)

Comment: Please show the code you are using and where exactly your issue is. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Parent
```

will give you the worksheet that contains the active chart.

Of course, if you have an `ActiveChart`, `ActiveSheet` also gives you the active sheet, which contains the active chart.